# How to put the JSON data in to another JSON data in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to send JSON data by using POST in Objective-C.

I have two NSDictionary , I want to put the first NSDictionary**(json_dst)** in to second NSDictionary**(json)**.

I try the following code , but it seems not correct...

```
NSString DEVICE_UUID = @"9c88da0c-5362-460b-8647-590a981d912e";
int command = 65536;

    NSDictionary *json_dst = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"type", @"Device",@"uuid",DEVICE_UUID, nil];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id",@"200",@"dst",json_dst,@"msgType",@"MESSAGE",@"msg",command, nil];
```

It will crash at `NSDictionary *json = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id",@"200",@"dst",json_dst,@"msgType",@"MESSAGE",@"msg",command, nil];`.

And the error log is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'
```

But I didn't know the reason...

Can somebody teach me how to do ? Did I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your main problem is that you've got objects and keys reversed.  You also can't insert numbers directly -- they must be NSNumber objects.

Comment: @HotLicks Excuse me , can you explain more. Which is number ?

Comment: "Number" was the `200`, before you edited your question to put it in quotes.

Comment: And `command` is a number.

Comment: Did you read my first comment???

Comment: **YOU HAVE THE OBJECTS AND KEYS REVERSED**

Comment: And when reporting a "crash" always supply the complete exception message and exception stack trace.

Comment: @Martin Using the newer Objective-C dictionary literal syntax is both shorter and easier to write.

Comment: The method is called objectsAndKeys, not keysAndObjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your keys and objects are in the wrong order.

Secondly you're trying to put a primitive type into the dictionary (command is an int). The dictionary must hold Objective-C instances, subclassing from NSObject.

Lastly your DEVICE_UUID is missing a pointer star (*).

To make the dictionary easier to use and to keep it in the order of key-value, I'll show using [modern Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Instead of putting the primitive in directly, you need to wrap it in an NSNumber. This can be done by "boxing" the number inside `@(command)`, another feature of literals.

```
NSString *DEVICE_UUID = @"9c88da0c-5362-460b-8647-590a981d912e";
int command = 65536;

NSDictionary *json_dst = @{@"type":@"Device", @"uuid":DEVICE_UUID};
NSDictionary *json = @{@"id":@"200", @"dst":json_dst, @"msgType":@"MESSAGE", @"msg":@(command)};
```

Comment: So the correct order is NSDictionary `*json_dst = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Device", @"type",DEVICE_UUID,@"uuid", nil];`.  Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @Martin if you want to write it using the -dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: method then yes the objects come first and the keys second, as the method name describes. However I'd recommend using what I've put in my answer, as it's easier to read.

Comment: It's also safer; you will be told if one of the objects is nil instead of silently producing an incorrect dictionary.